# Script Execution flow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, execution

```
$(function() {
    alert("hello World");
});
alert("hello");
```

**Output:**

first "hello" is alert /*which is on line 2*/ then "hello world" alerted
I want to know what is the execution rule in javascript

Comment: JS is event-driven, so flow coincides with the outside triggering of pre-defined events.

Answer (score 5):

This block will execute when dom is ready.

```
$(function() {
    alert("hello World");
});
```

This is similar to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

And 2nd alert doesn't wait for the dom ready.

that's why 2nd alert executes first.